# Output terraform outputs as variable in Azure DevOps pipeline YAML

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to get the variable from the Terraform output and show it/output it. Later I can pass this variable in another step.
Terraform outputs the json that I am trying to loop over and take the variable
However, when I want to see the output in the console in Azure DevOps I only get that the script is saved and cannot see any value written out and therefore check if the variable was correctly assigned.

I would like to output the value of reg_name but so far, even after successfully executing this part, I do not see any after run.
Any tips on what may be wrong here?

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Current code:

```
       - task: TerraformTaskV3@3
          name: terraformOutput
          inputs:
            provider: 'azurerm'
            command: 'output'
            workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/.azureDevOps/terraform'
            environmentServiceNameAzureRM: 'xxxxx'

        - task: AzurePowerShell@5
          inputs:
            azureSubscription: 'service-connection-creditrisk'
            ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
            Inline: |
              $json = Get-Content $(TerraformOutput.jsonOutputVariablesPath) | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
              foreach($prop in $json.psobject.properties) {
                  Write-Host("##vso[task.setvariable variable=$$prop.reg_name;]$($prop.reg_name.value)")
                }
            workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/.azureDevOps/terraform'
            azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
```

Comment: i've never tried doing something like that, are you sure that `$(TerraformOutput.jsonOutputVariablesPath)` exists and is not empty? what are the contents of the file?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Yes I can see that the json is created and that the the contents are the terraform outputs it just seems that i cant find the file in the next step

Comment: honestly, you dont need to do that in the terraform step, you can just do `terraform output -json | ConvertFrom-Json`

Answer (score 1):

If you follow this documentation:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=charleszipp.azure-pipelines-tasks-terraform#terraform-output-to-pipeline-variables

You can add the step:

```
- task: TerraformTaskV4@4
  name: terraformOutput
  inputs:
    provider: 'azurerm'
    command: 'output'
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/.azureDevOps/terraform'
    environmentServiceNameAzureRM: 'xxxxx'
```

This will set all outputs as `$(TF_OUT_<OUPUT NAME>)`
e.g. if the output was called `reg_name` then it would be `$(TF_OUT_REG_NAME)`